# How to drop property with its value in Java?

Tags: java

I am so new to Java world so please be kind.

I have one class which has some properties as below:

```
public class Test{     
        private long prop1;

        private long prop2;

        public long getProp1() {
            return prop1;
        }

        public void setProp1(long prop1) {
            this.prop1= prop1;
        }

        public long getProp2() {
            return prop2;
        }

        public void setProp2(long prop2) {
            this.prop2 = prop2;
        }
}
```

Now I am after some operation I have filled object of class Test which is going to be sent to oData for save purpose. Somehow I do not want prop2 to be inserted into the string which will go to oData call, so how can I drop prop2 along with its value?

[prop1=1, prop2=2]

Comment: I would presume you would have some sort of serializer (which changes data to JSON, XML, etc). Usually you can specify which fields make it to the serialized result and which not. You would need to include how is your class being serialized for us to be in a better position to help.

Comment: If that is how you are sending data, then it might be useful to have a separate method and call that one before sending.

Comment: Worst case you can have a similar class without prop2 (`TestReduced`) that has a constructor that takes a `Test` object and basically copies everything *but* prop2. Then you can use your `Test` object as long as you need prop2 and create a `TestReduced` *from it* once you need to do your stuff that should not ever get in contact with `prop2`. A bit convoluted, but it would get the job done.

Comment: We still need to know how your serialization (?) is actually happening. Anyway, I made an answer out of my comment above, hoping that it suits your scenario. But really, more info would be helpful.

Comment: Your first comment resolved my issue, I created another class which do not have the property which I do not require.

Comment: Glad to hear! Make sure to use a common interface (or abstract base class) for both classes though, to ensure that both are (and stay) aligned, as pointed out in the answer.

Comment: Yes they are @domdom :) thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> thing is I require prop2 till one level to perform some operation but I need to remove it just before oData call, is it possible?

Not that I am aware of. Also, I don't know oData and your question is a bit hard to answer with the little info you provided. However, based on the above comment, I'm going to suggest two things:

## Approach #1: Reduced Class

```
public class Test {     
    private long prop1;
    private long prop2;

    /* getters, setters, ...*/
}

public class TestReduced {
    private long prop1;

    public TestReduced(Test test) {
        this.prop1 = test.getProp1();
    }

    /* getters, setters, ...*/
}
```

In other words, create a class that is similar to `Test`, bar the undesired member. In its constructor, copy every other member of the handed in `Test` object, effectively creating a copy that can be used for oData:

```
Test test1 = new Test();
test1.setProp1(1337L);
test1.setProp2(1007L);

/* Do something with test1, including prop2 */

TestReduced test2 = new TestReduced(test1);

/* Do oData stuff with test2, no prop2 anymore */
```

That's a pretty convoluted solution and it requires you to mirror all changes to `Test` in `TestReduced`. A common **interface** or an **abstract base class** could safeguard this process quite well, so I would definitely recommend putting one into place if you go with this. You should also consider adding a **private constructor** without parameters for `TestReduced` to make sure those can only be created from `Test` objects. Alternatively, let the `Test` class create instances of `TestReduced` with a method like `getReducedInstance()`, which would make `Test` a [factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)).

## Approach #2: Member Map

How about, instead of having two members, `prop1` and `prop2`, you use a Map?

```
public class Test {     
    private HashMap<String, Long> props = new HashMap<>();

    public Test() {
        props.put("prop1", 0L);
        props.put("prop2", 0L);
    }

    public void setProp1(long prop1) {
        props.put("prop1", p);
    }

    public void setProp2(long prop2) {
        props.put("prop2", p);
    }

    public long getProp1() {
        props.get("prop1");
    }

    public long getProp2() {
        props.get("prop2");
    }

    public void prepareForSerialization() {
        props.remove("prop2");
    }
}
```

Whether this works with oData, I don't know. But it surely is a pretty flexible way to handle an arbitrary number of properties. With your getters and setters, you can hide the implementation (`HashMap` vs. primitive type memebers). Or, if you prefer, you can expose it to the user by providing methods like `getProp(String name)` and `setProp(String name, long value)`. All of this is assuming that all your props are of type `long`.

---

Obviously, it would be better if you just had two methods for your serialization (?) purposes, one that includes `prop1`, one that doesn't. But since you explicitly said that you need to *remove* a member, this is what comes to my mind.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a method that elaborate that for you,

one option can be define a method and print the properties as you need...

you can as orientation, take a look to this autogenerated toString method

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "_Foo [prop1=" + prop1 + ", prop2=" + prop2 + "]";
}
```

remove the _Foo part and there you are!

Comment: Well I am already having that part in the class itself, thing is I require prop2 till one level to perform some operation but I need to remove it just before oData call, is it possible?

Comment: How about you add a boolean to your class, `serializeProp2`, that you can trigger via some method `enableProp2(boolean enable) { serializeProp2 = enable; }`, then in `toString()` you take that flag into account.